# How to change audio frequency with batch file

Tags: windows, batch

I'm playing some old games, that need a low frequency of sound, or it won't launch/launch without any sound in game. And it's annoying to always change frequency manually, just when I want to play specifically that game. And sometimes I forgot to change it back, after closing the game.

I decided to solve that problem with batch file, that will change frequency, launch game, and change it back, after closing.

Is it really possible to change frequency of sound, with batch?

[image: GUI area where the frequency is changed]

Comment: A screen shot of GUI area where the frequency is changed would help clarify some potentially. At least in terms of your question "*is it possible*" at least and technically with a "yes" or "no" sort of answer for such a question. That cat has some long pointed ears there too by the way.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT it's using my native language, but [here you are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDNqQ.png)

P.S. it's Caracal

Comment: Batch can't do it natively. But there may be programs that can do it. If there's one program that may be able to do so, it would be nircmd by NirSoft.

Comment: Batch may be able to do it "Windows" natively using some vb script logic in the batch and build it dynamically and execute with `script` or `wscript` potentially for any ideas for people that know how to and have the time. Another non-Windows native free solution that could help is AutoIT if you Google that up a bit. What language is that text by the way for someone that only reads English that were curious.